# Extracting SonarQube Report (preferably for Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

apologies if this has been covered, there have been a couple similar questions on SE - but struggling to find an explicit solution:

Does anyone know how to access the reports from SonarQube? I want to put some logic in Jenkins that will only proceed to do more stuff if quality gates are passed. This is something I wish to automate, and not login to sonarqube manually.

I have seen references to a possible, Gerrit plugin solution or using a curl step to use the API but neither explained how to replicate that approach.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to use the [SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/jenkins.html).

Specifically, check the "Analyzing in a Jenkins pipeline" section: it allows you to run a SonarQube analysis, and wait for the Quality Gate to be available so that you can decide (in your pipeline script) what to do based on the status of the quality gate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - however the reason we are having issues is we have the earlier version sonar-runner (using pipeline doesn't recognise the tool). We are trying to update from sonar 2.1 , but having issues due to possible dependencies/java installs. 
 Are you aware of any other method? many thanks

Comment: You're trying to update from Sonar 2.1, or from the Scanner for Jenkins 2.1? (it's not the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

sonarqube reports can be extracted using webapi
for example : http://sonarserver:9010/api/issues/search?componentKeys=sonarProject&severities=BLOCKER,CRITICAL,MAJOR,MINOR,INFO&s=SEVERITY&asc=false&ps=100
convert the json output to csv and to xls using online tools
http://convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm